# Catch an event when audio is going to play or starts to playing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, avaudioplayer

I have an UIWebView and if user starts listening to music that is inside this UIWebView I want to do some things.I need to catch event when music is starting to playing.I think I can do it using AVAudioPlayerDelegate or NSNotifications but really I am not sure how.Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: does your music play from webview or from your app?

Comment: from the UIWebView

Comment: so for that you can not use AVAudioPlayerDelegate.
You need to go through UIWebVIew Delegate methods which may help you

Comment: Nope , I have already tried this an that did not help.